# I have writen this code but I don't understand why it works like this

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, input, append

I have a code, It gets a number as n for the amount of number you want to give, then I have another input which is the numbers we want to give the code, I want my code to find the numbers lower than 3 and produce the output but it works pretty weirdly! so help me people, Thx a lot in advance

```
y = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    x = input()
    x = x.split()
    
    for j in x:
        j = int(j)
        if j < 3:
            for j in x:
                y.append(j)
                break
            print(y)
```

my input is like :
5
1 2 3

my output should be :
1 2

but it is like :
['1','1']

Comment: So you enter 5 for n, but only proceed to enter three numbers? Also, the indentations are out of whack, is that how it actually looks in your IDE or do you messed the formatting on pasting? Because the loop then goes for every input instead of after all input are processed

Comment: First, add the language tag please, secondly, why you need the inner loop? if j<3 just add it to the output array,

Comment: hey dear, Martheen. Yes I want to enter a few numbers, it doesn't really important, I want it to work the way I said, to find the numbers lower than 3 and put them in a list, the indentation is exactly the way that in my IDE

Comment: hi dear, @InUser  I added the language tag thank you for reminding me of this, I want exactly the same that you said but I can't handle it and don't know what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mix with the input.

Either you receive it as one input and then you need the split or you receive is one after another (n times).

In the first option you need to split the list and iterate over it and append, in the second option you just need to check each number and append it
In the list case you don't need the n in the beginning

```
y = []
x = input()
x = x.split()
for j in x:
    j = int(j)
    if j < 3:
        y.append(j)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
y = []
n = 5

x = "5 1 2 3 2"
x = x.split()
    
for j in x:  # for each value in x
    j = int(j)
    if j < 3:  # if < 3, append to list
       y.append(j)

print(y)
```

Now you can implement your function for obtaining the numbers and improve return.

Comment: Thx dear, Vinicius but the assignment is with input, but you helped me a lot and I appreciate that